# Drag and Drop list items between table cells - jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

In one of my projects I need to make list items drag/droppable between table cells. That means that one should be able to drag a list item from a table cell and drop it into another one and it should be saved in its new location. Could anybody suggest any plugin for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think next solution is simple and useful for your: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: I'm looking to do similar, did this solution work out well? Did it work within table cells ok or did you convert to lists?

Answer (score 1):

Table drag and drop plugin: http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Other drag and drop plugins: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/jquery-drag-drop-plugins.html

Comment: Thank you, however none of those is suitable. The first one sorts the table rows while I need to drag and drop items between table cells.

Answer (score 1):

Using an old example [from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875471/jquery-ui-sortable-connectwith-difficulties-when-connected-item-is-empty), you can add selectors to the cells and then verify them upon receive:

jQuery:

```
function(e, ui){
    var dropId = ui.item.attr("id");
    alert(dropId);
    if (dropId == "top1" || dropId == "top2") {
        $("#a").append(ui.item);   
    } else if (dropId == "bottom1" || dropId == "bottom2") {
        $("#b").append(ui.item);   
    }
}
```

A bit too late but maybe for future help: [demo click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLzU3/188/)