# Drag and drop in side a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

How do I drag and drop an elemet from one  to another and all other s align themselves accordingly in a 3x3 table using jquery? Please help me out here. I am really confused.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".smsSecond").draggable({containment: ".maincol"});//, revert: true

    $(".smsSecond").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(500);
    });

    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {

    $('.smsSecond').show(500);

    return false;

});
});
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far...

Comment: The above code is what i have tried so far.
Its just for dragging the elements from one place to another and I am confused about what I told in the question. @Myth

Comment: I think this answer can sole your problem...
[Jquery UI sortable][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875471/jquery-ui-sortable-connectwith-difficulties-when-connected-item-is-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try jQuery UI, the example and resource is [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable). You can change it to fit your needs.